# Clustering java standalone application

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I am working on a java standalone app which reads big files (500 Mo), deserializes these files (protobuf message - Google api) and inserts it into oracle 11 DB.

Important thing to say is that there is one main table in database, and several small tables (can be compare to dictionnaries).
For all dictionnaries, i have a Google cache (Guava).
There is no cache for the main table. In the main table there is only insertion, no update, no delete.

At the moment, this application runs onto a single JVM.
(Potentially, i can add multithreading.)

I would like to make it works on several JVM.
My problem is to know what to do in order to get higher performance and to make it works properly.
I identified two problems : if clustering the app will allow me to read several files at the same time, how to make the insertion into the main table faster, and how to update the cache?

Does someone have an idea about that?

Comment: Please tag more carefully. This is not [tag:cluster-analysis] (aka: clustering, a data mining technique), but you want parallelization.

Comment: You're right. thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

> how to make the insertion into the main table faster

Jackpot! You must identify your bottlenecks and most likely it's either reading files or the database. Files are simple, just split them and put on different machines. Of course running several JVMs on the same machine won't help since they will all compete for I/O. So you must split the files and distribute them over several machines, together with JVMs.

I assume deserializing protobuf is not a bottleneck, it requires some CPU, but not that much.

And finally you have a database. It's possible that a single, single-threaded JVM can fully utilize the database, but it's worth trying. First make your app multi-threaded and see whether it helps.

> how to update the cache?

Jackpot again. You'll have to distribute/cluster your cache as well. Guava cache is not enough, you'll need something more sophisticated like RMI clustered EhCache, Terracotta or Hazelcast. Basically they provide cache API but notify other members of the cluster that cache changed and needs to invalidate.

BTW 500 MiB is not really that much, how long does it take to process? Again, you must profile to find what's slowing you down.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will supply more infos about the time elapsed next week, cause i don't want to make a mistake by saying something wrong. Nevertheless, I can't say the insertion process is slow, but i want it to be able to manage more files.

Comment: BTW protobuf is really quick, but It uses a lot of memory... This is the limit. Thanks again. More info about this next week.